# Question about Haussdorff measure being infinity

Tags: real-analysis, hausdorff-measure

I have a set of the following form $N = \{ (x_1, ...., x_n, f_1(x), ..., f_s(x): x \in (-1, 1)^n  \}$ with each $f_j$ smooth. This is an $n$ dimensional manifold. I think it is the case that
the $d$ dimension Hausdorff measure of $N$ is infinity as soon as $d < n$, that is to say $H^d(N) = \infty$.

I think it just amounts to finding a suitable cover of $N$, but I have been struggling to prove it.. any pointers or reference would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, **an $n$-dimensional manifold $N$ has Hausdorff dimension $n$**.  And therefore $H^d(N) = \infty$ for all $d<n$ and $H^d(N) = 0$ for all $d>n$.  So your question is part of the proof of the statement in bold.  Hint: Do first the case where $f_1,\dots, f_s$ are all constant zero.

Comment: I think I get it now, thank you!

Comment: Is your question about the Hausdorff *dimension* being infinite, or the Hausdorff *measure* being infinite in some specified dimension?

Comment: I meant Hausdorff measure, let me fix it thank you